# how to set timer in android using retrofit in android using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to get a response in 30 seconds but I am not able to get it in time. I am using `Retrofit 2` to make an API call. In `Postman` checking with `emailId` and `password` getting success response. My application also getting success response but after success, activity is not moving to next activity.

Can anyone help me with `Retrofit` to set a timeout.

```
String url = "xxxxxx";
Retrofit retrofit = null;
Log.d("123", "retrofit");

if (retrofit == null) {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    Log.d("123", "build();");
}

final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
dialog.setMessage("Authenticating...." + 30000 / 1000 + " Second(s)");
dialog.setIndeterminate(false);

new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // You don't need anything here
        dialog.setMessage("Authenticating....");
        if (!dialog.isShowing()) dialog.show();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
    }
}.start();

API1 service = retrofit.create(API1.class);
Call<Login> call = service.authenticate(emailId, password);
Log.i(TAG, "Sending---" + url + service + url + "\n" + "emailId:" + emailId + "\n" + "password:" + password);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {

        if (response != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.code() == 200) {
            String status = response.body().getStatus().toString();
            Log.i(status, "success");
            if (status.equals("success")) {
                // dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent mainIntent;
                mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "No Response from the server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid EmailId and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
        // Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
        // dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: **Please don't repeat questions.** Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you seem to have gotten your solution there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen i have updated the duplicate target question check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the read and connect timeouts using [Okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/).

You will need to add a dependency in `build.gradle`

> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'

**EXAMPLE**

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl(Constants.WEB_SERVICE)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

Comment: it is showing error newBuilder()

Comment: updated answer. please check

Comment: after adding this timer is the controller will go to  this class or not DeviceControlActivity.class

Comment: If you are getting Success response, it will go, 
it basically increases the connect / read timeout. other logics are up to you